# How to automatically change the value list of option of select tag when i select the certain option of another select tag HTML <select>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<select>
  <option>america</option>
  <option>rusia</option>
  <option>china</option>
</select>
<select>   <!--here the second select tag which has so many option value-->
  <option>list1</option>
  <option>list2</option>
  <option>list3</option>
</select>
```

How to dynamically change the value of tghe second select tag when I choose the first select?

For example, if I choose america, the second select option list will show washington,new york,etc, but when I choose rusia, it will show moscow, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to select `<option>` at same index within both `<select>` elements?

Comment: what have you tried so far?can you add what you have tried so far including the proper HTML, the js , css etc...

Comment: what i want here is the second select will show certain list of option when i select the first select. basically the second select have so many option value

Comment: By the way, I think "rusia" should have been "Russia".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event attached to all `<select>` elements, set `selectedIndex` of each `select` element to the current `change` `event.target` element `selectedIndex` utilizing `.each()` excluding current element, `this`,  with `.not()`

```js
var select = $("select");
select.change(function(e) {
  select.not(this).each(function() {
    this.selectedIndex = e.target.selectedIndex
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>america</option>
  <option>rusia</option>
  <option>china</option>
</select>
<select>   <!--here the second select tag which has so many option value-->
  <option>list1</option>
  <option>list2</option>
  <option>list3</option>
</select>
```